# Set and Get Method

Tags: java, object, methods, get, set

I have a class using set and get to print out information for objects I have created in my main. My issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to use the values entered for my objects to do calculations within a different method and print out the correct results. I need to divide LDL by HDL, but the results keep coming out to 0 and my if statement still executes regardless. Can anyone please guide in the right direction on how to properly use get and set methods and using them with other methods that do calculations? Also I cannot seem to understand why a constructor is needed because it seems to me that the set does the same exact thing. Below is the code for both my main class, user defined class, and what comes out when executed.

```
public class Checkup {

//Fields
private int patientNumber;
private int systolic;
private int diastolic;
private double ldl;
private double hdl;
private double results;

//Constructor
public Checkup(int number, int sys, int dia, double l, double h) {

    patientNumber = number;
    systolic = sys;
    diastolic = dia;
    ldl = l;
    hdl = h;
}

//Set Methods
public void setPatientNumber(int number) {

    patientNumber = number;
}

public void setSystolic(int sys) {

    systolic = sys;
}

public void setDiastolic(int dia) {

    diastolic = dia;
}

public void setLDL(double l) {

    ldl = l;
}

public void setHDL(double h) {

    hdl = h;
}


//Get Methods
public int getPatientNumber() {

    return patientNumber;
}

public int getSystolic() {

    return systolic;
}

public int getDiastolic() {

    return diastolic;
}

public double getLDL() {

    return ldl;
}

public double getHDL() {

    return hdl;
}

//LDL and HDL calculation methods
public void setComputeRatio(double l, double h) {

    results = l / h;
}

public double getComputeRatio() {

    return results;
}

//Print Methods
public void printCheckup() {

    System.out.println(getPatientNumber());
    System.out.println(getSystolic());
    System.out.println(getDiastolic());
    System.out.println(getLDL());
    System.out.println(getHDL());
    System.out.println(getComputeRatio());
    if (getComputeRatio() <= 3.5) {

        System.out.println("HDL is known as \"Good Cholesterol\" and a ratio of 3.5 or lower          is considered optimum");
    }
    System.out.println();

}
```

}

and this my main:

```
public class TestCheckup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Checkup personA = new Checkup(90880, 110, 78, 100.0, 40.0);
        Checkup personB = new Checkup(2,3,4,5.0,6.0);
        //Checkup personC = new Checkup();
        //Checkup personD = new Checkup();

        personA.printCheckup();
        personB.printCheckup();

    }
}
```

and what is printed:

```
90880
110
78
100.0
40.0
0.0
HDL is known as "Good Cholesterol" and a ratio of 3.5 or lower is considered optimum

2
3
4
5.0
6.0
0.0
HDL is known as "Good Cholesterol" and a ratio of 3.5 or lower is considered optimum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting an output of 0.0 for the `getComputeRatio()` method is because you never actually made any changes to the `results` instance variable after construction. During construction `results` was implicitly set to 0.0. In essence, it were as if your constructor were written like so:

```
public Checkup(int number, int sys, int dia, double l, double h) {

    patientNumber = number;
    systolic = sys;
    diastolic = dia;
    ldl = l;
    hdl = h;
    results = 0.0; // <====
}
```

After that, however, the variable is never touched again... To better explain what I mean, take a look at the following sample code:

```
public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create a new Checkup object
        Checkup personA = new Checkup(1, 2, 3, 4.0, 5.0);

        // Calculate ratio
        personA.setComputeRatio(personA.getLDL(), personA.getHDL()); // <== This is needed...

        // Get results
        personA.printCheckup(); // ... before you do this. Otherwise results will always equal 0.0
    }
}
```

Now in your original post you asked:

> *"Can anyone please guide in the right direction on how to properly use get and set methods and using them with other methods that do calculations?"*

One way to accomplish this would be to make the following change to your `setComputeRatio(...)` method definition:

```
public void setComputeRatio() {

    results = getLDL() / getHDL();

    /* 
    Or you could also do:
    results = ldl / hdl; 
    */   
}
```

The above code not only implements your previously created get methods, but does so in a calculation. It also makes things less cumbersome and awkward, for example:

```
 // Calculate ratio
 personA.setComputeRatio(personA.getLDL(), personA.getHDL());
```

can now be shortened to:

```
// Calculate ratio
 personA.setComputeRatio();
```

Hope this helps!

Kind regards,
KLM

Comment: I tried changing the body of the method in setComputeRatio with both the getLDL() / getHDL() and ldl / hdl, but it still produced 0.0 as the answer. Can you elaborate on exactly why this is happening?

Comment: @AJ_ Made some much needed edits to my above answer. Hopefully it's clearer now. :)

Comment: It worked! Thank you very very much. This definitely helped me understand set and get methods a whole lot better.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I missed it, but are you calling your `setComputeRatio()` method before calling the `getComputeRatio()` method?

Comment: I was trying to call the return of my setComputeRatio with getComputeRatio and printing out the calculated return in my print method.